# Using Webgrid to create <th> tag

Tags: webgrid

I tried to render a table using WebGrid, but the structure that using WebGrid render doesn't contain `<th>` tag, and it renders only `<td>` inside `<tr>` tag inside ''.

Can anyone help me how to render `<th>` tag without using `<table>`?
such as :
`

```
      <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th> </th>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
         </tbody>
       </table>
```

`

Thx a lot

Answer (score 1):

The WebGrid will render `th` elements by default unless you set the displayHeader parameter to false. It will render them in a `tr` within a `thead` element. Additionally, it will always render an opening `<table>` tag. If you don't want an opening `<table>` tag, you will have to manually construct whatever HTML you want to render.